# How to override Xbase rule and call super rule?

Tags: xtext

Suppose I want to extend Xbase XExpression in my grammar:

`XExpression:
   super| MyRule;`

as [described here](http://zarnekow.blogspot.de/2015/11/improved-grammar-inheritance.html). But I cannot figure out how to override the Xbase XExpression.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. The trick is to import Xbase

```
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase

XExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
    super | MyRule
;

MyRule:
    'doit' expression= XExpression
;
```